# MS Graph : Create webhooks for multiple channels within same team

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Does MS Graph API support webhooks to be created per team instead of per channel per team or complete org wide. I see there are 2 different webhooks that can be created : 1. teams/allMessages and 2. teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages

The first one subscribes to all teams tenant/org wide, whereas the second is more granular. The problem when I subscribe with second one is, after creating one subscription if I want to subscribe to another channel within the same team, MS graph returns an error -

```
"error": {\r\n "code": "ExtensionError",\r\n "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: BadRequest; Reason: App <app-id> has reached its limit of 1 TEAMS/<team-id>/CHANNELS/<channel-id>/MESSAGES subscription on tenant <tenant-id>."
```

How can we subscribe to multiple channels within the same team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to have one active subscription per channel per application.

Additionally there is a limit of 10000 subscriptions for teams messages per tenant for all applications.

Check that you're not over that limit and that you're not trying to create a second subscription for the same channel

Comment: Upvoted.  The behavior of the service when the subscription expires can cause confusion via this error.  If the subscription is allowed to expire, two things happen: it gets deleted (if you try to DELETE it will return a 404), but you will get the error mentioned by @hkadakia for at least 1-2 minutes when you try to recreate a subscription on the channel.  i.e. DELETE before your subscription expires.  Just adding in case this saves someone pain.

Comment: @socasanta thanks for adding that precision. That or patch the expiration date before it expires to extend the subscription

Comment: Ah, that's even better!

Comment: @baywet Thanks, I can create subscriptions per team per channel. But another problem I see now is I do not receive any notifications when I have subscriptions per channel. When I have teams/allMessages webhook created, I get all notifications promptly but never get any notifications when webhook is per channel

Comment: What change type did you subscribe to?

Comment: Can you open a support ticket for it please?