# Getting ResourceNotFound when renewing an existing teams subscription

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I have an app that has 2 tenant-level subscriptions, one for tenant teams channels and one for teams chats.

When I try to renew the subscription for Teams chats I get:
`{'code': 'ResourceNotFound', 'message': 'The object was not found.', 'innerError': {'date': '2020-07-08T11:21:52', 'request-id': '977e5beb-4eb1-484c-9d66-4ddc1db4ebb7'}}`

however, if I try to GET that same subscription I do get it, what means it exists, so why am I getting 404 when trying to renew it?

The renew subscription request Im sending works just fine for the other subscription (Teams Channels), so I know that I'm building the request correctly (PATCH, url: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions/{subscription_id}`, paylod contains only new `expirationDateTime` )

In addition, if I try to create the subscription I get an error saying only one subscription is allowed for that resource, which is consist with the fact that I can GET the subscription... so why cant I renew it?

Comment: How close are you to the subscription expiration when you try to renew it? Out of curiosity what happens if you try to delete it and recreate it?

Comment: For reference see the comments of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62785332/3808675